# Pentaho | GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: garbage-collection, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-data-integration

I want to insert data from xlsx file into table. Excel has around 1,20,000 records. But while running transformation, I am getting below error:

> GC overhead limit exceeded

I have changed in `spoon.bat`.

```
Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

But still I am getting this error.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Try bumping Xmx even more and see if that helps. Also it's worth using `ps` command to see if the params you've set actually apply to the process.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case , additional to adding the Xms and Xmx parameters(which didnt solve it completly) i added the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to spoon.sh and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it work I increate the memory to 4GB issue is fixed.

if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2048m" "-Xmx4096m"

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with apache POI.
the xlsx input step is not able to read big files.
I usually turn my files into CVS in such cases.
here is the jira case.
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-5269

The environment variable PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS is used to add option to the starting of jre. Mine is set to "-Xms512m -Xmx3000M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Answer (score 0):

Split the file into two different files, save half of the data in one file and the remaining in another. It works perfectly.